# How to check the running Pi desktop session from terminal on Raspbian Stretch?

Tags: pi-3, raspbian-stretch, desktop

How to check the running Pi desktop session from terminal on Raspbian Stretch? And does desktop session even run on a headless scenario?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming SSH is enabled, you should be able to run desktop headless just fine.  I don't see what would be the point as many resources would be used to draw windows and such which you wouldn't see.  You can check what's happening process wise with

```
ps -aux
```

or something like

```
top
```

Comment: because I am getting a tiny desktop with `x0vncserver` as it loads the 0 dektop (the main desktop), so was looking for a fix in the de may be and it is showing that `lxde-pi` is running as I did `ps aux | grep de`. So wish me luck.